# Can't Load URL from Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting the following error when attempting to login with Facebook on my app:

> **Can't Load URL**: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

- The app home URL is: https://account.kodular.io
- The redirect URL is: https://account.kodular.io/a/access/facebook

---

The app status is live, and everything that has to be configured is properly set:

[image: App Domains]
[image: Site URL]
[image: Domain Manager]
[image: OAuth Settings]

Even the redirection validator sais the URL is valid

[image: Redirect Validator]

What am I doing wrong?